# How do I display an image in html using webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I've installed file-loader and url-loader, and added the below to my webpack config

```
     {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
      },
```

below is my html

```
<img src="../src/assets/laughing.svg">
```

console error after npm run dev

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I'm new to webpack, not sure what I'm doing wrong here....
Full config:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack App',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack App',
      filename: 'about.html',
      template: 'src/about.html',
    }),
  ],
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Image works when I'm not not running npm run dev. So img src must be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove file-loader and url-loader

**Here's the documentation example:**

```
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
     filename: 'bundle.js',
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.css$/i,
         use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
       },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource', // EXAMPLE HERE
      },
     ],
   },
 };
```

only use the asset/resource module